# How to inject data into a page that is rendered on *each request* to Angular Universal server?

Tags: angular, angular-universal

With nextjs, it is explained very clearly right out of the box ("getServerSideProps").

With angular universal, it's not at all clear. I'd like to implement an app whereby on, each request, the app will fetch/compute data, use it to render a page, and then return that page with the data already in it (viewable in e.g. "View Source" in a Chrome browser).

Can someone explain how it works or point me to a simple working example? Thanks